# Getting records of through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following standard `has_many :through` association:

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments

  scope :healthy, -> { where("last_visited_on < ?", 5.years.ago) }
end
```

Now, I need to get the names of a specific physician's healthy patients.
I tried the merge below

```
specific_physician = Physician.first
Patient.healthy.merge(Patient.where(physician: specific_physician).pluck(:name)
```

But got an error on the constructed SQL query

> ERROR:  column patients.physicians does not exist (PG::UndefinedColumn)

How can I get patients associated with a specific physician?

Comment: Any physician. See the updated request. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Physician` instance has `patients` method

`Patient` relation has `healthy` scope

Just chain these methods

```rb
specific_physician.patients.healthy.pluck(:name)
```

You can also modify your code, but probably it is not so elegant

```rb
Patient.joins(:physicians).healthy.where(physicians: { id: specific_physician.id}).pluck(:name)
```